# Password fields on page and SSL certificates

Tags: php, ssl

I have a security question.  Must your webpage be on https (SSL certificate) if there is a login box available on the page through modal requiring username and password?  Or do just the login assets have to be on https?

My website has browsable content that does not require login to access, however the option to login is available within the header of every page.

My website has a login similar to www.fab.com for example (browsable content with the option to login).

I am having problems with Firefox disabling functionality due to mixed content, even though I am taking measures of removing protocol within my asset links.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Must*, no; is it a good idea: usually

Answer (score 0):

First, it security.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask this question.
But to your question: SSL (https) provides identification of the peer and end-to-end encryption. So if you submit the data with https you can be sure, that nobody manipulated the submitted data.

But if you don't load the form over https too, somebody could have manipulated it, like changing the submission target. So you should never serve sensitive forms with http but submit to https.

Apart from that there are still enough ways for an attacker to get to the data:

- Manipulate a page served over http to include a form, even if the original page would not have one. Especially with login forms this tricks lots of users. So you better serve everything with https.
- Intigrate fake forms in your page by misusing places for ads etc. So you better do not include any third party script on your page (ads, tracking, social...) and if you use ads restrict them to iframes which are placed so that they can never trick the user by displaying fake forms
- and probably more

Answer (score 0):

> Must your webpage be on https (SSL certificate) if there is a login box available on the page through modal requiring username and password? Or do just the login assets have to be on https?

It depends on the dataflows. One dataflow is:

```
      Client                          Server
===================================================

username, password    ----->
```

The `{username,password}` pair is valued, so it must be protected. You can do the whole site with HTTPS, of just the login over Socket.IO or WebSocket as long as its using HTTPS or WSS.

Another dataflow to watch out for is the token or cookie being returned:

```
      Client                          Server
===================================================

                      <-----     token or cookie
```

The token or cookie has value because it provides subsequent access, so it also needs to be protected.

If you have not created an analyzed dataflows, it might be a good thing to do.

Also, you should not mix and match HTTP and HTTPS content due to downgrade attacks. That kind of means everything should be HTTPS.

And you also have [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), [CSPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy), WebApp Sandboxing, etc to contend with. Things are only getting worse with the HTML imports and the XSS they provide.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are allowing users log-in on every page, I must say you should TURN-ON SSL. There isn't any side-effects at all, in fact you'll have more chances to gain visitors trust to access your site hassle-free.

If we talk about mixed content error on Mozilla Firefox, I recommend you to develop your site with relative path (`<a href="/pages.html">`) instead of absolute path (forcefully whole URL (`<a href="https://www.domain.com/pages.html">`). Follow url to get brief solution on this issue: https://www.clickssl.com/blog/how-to-stop-secure-and-nonsecure-items-warning-on-your-site